# QtSpim - How can I change .ascii value in .data?

Tags: mips, qtspim

I load address of the .ascii with "flores" and I want change this to my name. I can put only my forename next to flores, but I want replace "flores" to "kyanoz"

```
User data segment [10000000]..[10040000]
[10000000]..[1000ffff]  00000000
[10010000]    1919904870  0000029541  0000000000  0000000000    f l o r e s . . . . . . . . . . 
[10010010]    0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000006    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
[10010020]..[1003ffff]  00000000
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you should edit your post and add your mips code. It is difficult to give you an answer without it as a hex dump of the area doesn't help too much.

Comment: I fail to see why you would be able to store the other string after the first string, but not overwrite the first string. Just change the address you're writing to so that you start at the address where the first string begins.